# NuGet not resolving libraries on TFS Build

Tags: tfs, msbuild, nuget, mvvmcross

I have a solution containing two projects that use MVVM Cross.  Both build and publish on dev machines, however, we're trying to publish these from a TFS build using a command such as the following:

```
MSBuild /target:publish /property:PublishDir=\\serverDir\
```

The problem I have is that despite both building fine and publishing locally, with the same command, on the build machine, they fail to find the `Cirrious` namespace.  My guess is that, for some reason, NuGet is not correctly resolving the packages.

Has anyone come across a similar issue, or have any idea how to resolve this?

EDIT:

Thanks to @MrHinsh comments, I think I've identified that the issue.  The project in question is referencing CrossCore like this:

```
<Reference Include="Cirrious.CrossCore">
  <HintPath>..\..\..\packages\MvvmCross.HotTuna.CrossCore.3.2.1\lib\portable-win+net45+wp8+win8+wpa81+MonoTouch+MonoAndroid\Cirrious.CrossCore.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

However, only CrossCore.3.1.1 is source controlled.  I can easily fix this, but I suspect that there is a problem in that these are not being retrieved each build.

Comment: Can you do a build locally on the build server and make sure all is well? Could be coms issues on the box

Comment: Get the same errors when executing the MSBuild command locally on the build agent